# json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type Auction.Item

Tags: json, serialization, go

I have a problem deserializing my object. I use an interface to this object to call the Serialization, and from reading the output the serialization works perfectly. Here is the underlying struct of my object:

```
type pimp struct {
    Price       int
    ExpDate     int64
    BidItem     Item
    CurrentBid  int
    PrevBidders []string
}
```

And here's the interface it implements:

```
type Pimp interface {
    GetStartingPrice() int
    GetTimeLeft() int64
    GetItem() Item
    GetCurrentBid() int
    SetCurrentBid(int)
    GetPrevBidders() []string
    AddBidder(string) error
    Serialize() ([]byte, error)
}
```

The Serialize() method:

```
func (p *pimp) Serialize() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(*p)
}
```

As you may have noticed, pimp has a variable by the name of Item. This item is also, an interface:

```
type item struct {
    Name string
}

type Item interface {
    GetName() string
}
```

Now serializing a sample of such an object returns the following JSON:

```
{"Price":100,"ExpDate":1472571329,"BidItem":{"Name":"ExampleItem"},"CurrentBid":100,"PrevBidders":[]}
```

Here is my deserialization code:

```
func PimpFromJSON(content []byte) (Pimp, error) {
    p := new(pimp)
    err := json.Unmarshal(content, p)
    return p, err
}
```

Running it, however, gives me the following error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type Auction.Item
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't unmarshal into empty interfaces, because the json package has no way to know what concrete type to use inside that interface.

Comment: Is there any way to tell it what type it is? Kind of like [`json:"varName"`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)?

Comment: No, since types can't be referenced by name (if you don't use the type directly, it may not even be in your compiled binary). It's better to try not to unmarshal into interfaces (other than using `interface{}` for json package default types).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unmarshaler does not know the concrete type to use for the nil `BidItem` field. You can fix this by setting the field to a value of the appropriate type:

```
func PimpFromJSON(content []byte) (Pimp, error) {
    p := new(pimp)
    p.BidItem = &item{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(content, p)
    return p, err
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/6HoyLPmjJm)